# Laravel-4 routes with parameters gets called twice

Tags: php, laravel-4

I noticed strange behaviour occuring for my activation route for an application that I'm developing using laravel and after hours of debugging through xdebug etc, it came into an observation that my route was actually called twice at times. To recreate the situation, I created a fresh new laravel project with default files and just added a simple route as a test that does the following:

```
Route::get('/activate/{code}', function($code)
{
   file_put_contents('/home/fa/testproj/route_called.txt', $code . "\n",   FILE_APPEND);
});
```

Basically what this simple route does is to take the route parameter passed on the URI and logs it into a file. Strangely, I noticed that the routes were called twice for code parameter that I typed on the URI (such as `http://myserver/activate/123456789`), but only once for repeated codes (probably due to some session caching?). The content of the 'route_called.txt' file for multiple tries was as follow:

```
123456789
123456789
123838384242
123838384242
123838384242        <---- notice that it's called only once for repeated parameter
1238383842424657347
1238383842424657347
332211576347
332211576347
332211576347    <---- notice that it's called only once for repeated parameter
1238376540897326
1238376540897326
```

The laravel files are fresh and I've not changed anything except for the four lines of route codes as above. I have standard files provided by laravel in the public folder:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fa fa    0 Apr 15 16:06 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fa fa  356 Apr 15 16:06 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fa fa 1586 Apr 15 16:06 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 fa fa 4096 Apr 15 16:06 packages/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fa fa   24 Apr 15 16:06 robots.txt
```

The .htaccess is untouched too as provided by laravel:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My server is Ubuntu 12.04LTS, running Apache 2.2.22 with all the standard php modules required by laravel.

Some people say elsewhere that this could be due to missing favicon.ico issue but laravel has taken care of this problem by already providing us with the favicon.ico file as above.

Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: How is the route called? via normal link (http get request) or via ajax request? If it's ajax, you might have some issue with JS event bubbling up.

Comment: via normal http get request

Comment: What if you run it locally on the PHP built in webserver? Just to see if it is a Laravel problem or Apache related.

Comment: In my laravel environemnt (laravel 4.1.28), the above route function is called only one time. Is there any effect of your browser's add-on or anti-virus software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its ok folks, I managed to find the answer why the strange behaviour was so. It's nothing to do with Laravel at all. It seems that the internet filtering device at the ISP level was what sending the duplicate HTTP requests to my server. I guess the device would send duplicate requests mimicking our browsing page requests in order to check whether the sites that we visit complies with the filtering policies... Had to redesign some logics of my app in order to cater situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and i solved it. My problem was from laravel middlewares.
Please check your custom middlewares. Hope help : ).. .

Comment: Can you elaborate on what was wrong in your middleware?

Comment: I think `$next($request)` was called 2 times.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue one time, after many attempts a realized that i used a image tag on a blade file like this :

```
<img src='#' />
```

that `#` symbol caused that each file that contains that image tries to get an image with the current route address .

this putted me to work for a couple of days!

Answer (score 0):

I called it at the first line of my custom middleware:

```
$response = $next($request);
```

and used this variable to next line where i need to use the closure: `$next($reques`t)

i removed the first line and now it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having the same issue in the AWS hosted app, non in local...after hours trying figure it out what was happening, we found that for some reason(maybe something in the deployment process) a Unit Test of this route was triggering the call twice.....if this is your case try commenting any Unit Test and then find why that behavior is happening!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I was using `redirect()` in my controller, however, the request was sent by ajax, redirect was useless in that case. I removed it and only kept my redirection code in the success callback of my ajax call.

```
success: function(response) {
    location.replace('/mailbox');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. A Laravel 8 app that was calling the route (url) twice. The problem only happened when calling it from a cronjob at the server (at cloudways) with wget or curl. At my local dev pc, there was no problem. If I called the url using the browser, again, there was no problem.

After a few days strugling with this, I found out the culprit was the varnish cache in the server. Turning it off solved the problem. Varnish was already turned off at APP level. I had to turn it off at the servel level!

Hope this might help someone who stumbles upon this thread in the future.