# Link called twice even if it just echoes a word

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

I do not know why if I click on a normal link the call sometimes (not all the times) is done twice.

This is the code of the link to the page:

```
<a href="{{ url('test') }}">TEST</a>
```

The route for the test `route` is just:

```
Route::get('test', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    Log::info("URL");
    Log::info(url()->current());
    $get_first = function($x){
        return $x[0];
    };
    Log::info("HEADERS");
    Log::info(array_map($get_first, $request->headers->all()));
    Log::info("REQUEST");
    Log::info($request->all());
    echo 'test';
});
```

When I click on the link, sometimes I have these lines in the apache2 access logs:

```
myurl.lvh.me:80 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2019:10:24:32 +0200] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 920 "http://myurl.lvh.me/?token=string" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myurl.lvh.me:80 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2019:10:24:33 +0200] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 927 "http://myurl.lvh.me/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

And of course in the laravel log I get twice the log of the `test` route.
As you can see there are 2 lines in the access logs, but I do not know why.

I read on other SO posts that the browser calls for favicon.ico, but it does not seem this is the case.

These are the 2 posts I found out to solve my problem:
[site is called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926943/site-is-called-twice)
[Controller action called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746190/controller-action-called-twice)

Comment: The referrer for both entries is different; for the second one, it seems to be the same URL itself, indicating that this request was likely indeed triggered by something _on_ that result page. Try and see if you can spot anything in your browser dev tools network panel, the “initiator” column might shed some light if this is due to some external script or something.

Comment: (Stuff like empty src attributes for images or script elements, or empty hrefs for `link` elements used to be “classic” triggers for this kind of stuff - but HTML5 has introduced explicit steps for browsers to detect this and avoid the extra request in such cases.)

Comment: @04FS but the result page just echoes a string. the html of the page is just the string.

Comment: If this is standard log file format, then the 920 / 927 values indicate how many bytes your server sent back in the response body. Apart from that `test` on its own can hardly amount to these numbers of bytes, this also indicates that your system’s response is _different_ in both cases.

Comment: Does moving the function to the controller have the same result?